# the imageai module requires Pytorch to work in Python3.10

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, torchvision, imageai

I am trying to install imageai in Python3.10. It is installed but when I import the module imageai, it requires installing pytorch and torchvision:

`Dependency error!!! PyTorch and TorchVision are not installed. Please see installation instructions in the documentation https://imageai.readthedocs.io/`

I installed Pytorch and Torchvision using the below commands in CMD:
`pip3.10 install torch pip3.10 install torchvision`

Yet I receive the above dependency error when I import imageai. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try to use the exact versions of the dependencies listed in the instructions of [imageai](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/).
I have uninstalled all modules first, then installed with the exact versions and the problem is solved.
I am using  `python 3.8.5`.
I hope this works with you also.